Ask: gz file and json file not loaded Azure web app static
i currently have azure web app static free tier and it need to load gz & json file from index.html, however when i checked the site through browser console network the file took long time to response
i had test in local it work and just wondering whether i need to do something with the staticwebapp.config.json due at first i thought it cause by path target to the file but it seems not that the cause
gz data load
json file load
this is the code which only in html & ajax for call the gz file
// Fetch the compressed GeoJSON data from new_data.gz
$.ajax({
    // url: '/special-reports/ground-truths/map/new_data.gz',
    url: 'new_data.gz',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip' },
    xhrFields: {
        responseType: 'arraybuffer' // Set response type to handle binary data
    },
    success: function (compressedData) {
        try {
            // Log the raw data received for debugging
            console.log("Compressed data received:", compressedData);

            // Decompress the data using pako.ungzip
            var decompressedData = pako.ungzip(new Uint8Array(compressedData), { to: 'string' });

            // Parse the decompressed data as JSON
            var geojson = JSON.parse(decompressedData);
            console.log("GeoJSON data loaded successfully.");

            // Process the GeoJSON data
            processGeojsonData(geojson);
        } catch (error) {
            // Log error details if decompression or parsing fails
            console.error("An error occurred while processing the GeoJSON data:", error);
        }
    }
});

below also the structure of the files
structure files directory
and content of staticwebapp.config.json
{
  "routes": [
    {
        "route": "/special-reports/ground-truths/map",
        "serve": "/special-reports/ground-truths/map/index_test.html",
        "statusCode": 200
    }
],
  "mimeTypes": {
        ".json": "text/json",
        ".gz": "text/gzip"
  }

}
thank you

Please provide more details like framework, version.

Share your code what you have tried?

Have you added staticwebapp.config.json file to your project?

The issue might be related to your free plan; try upgrading to a standard plan.

hi @AsleshaKantamsetti, thank you, the code is only use ajax inside index.html and the file gz itself is in same directory of index.html as well
For staticwebapp.config.json i only add routes for path directory though, may i know what should i add aside from routes ?

Add this lines to your staticwebapp.config.json file   "mimeTypes": {
".gz": "application/gzip",
".json": "application/json"
}.

sorry @AsleshaKantamsetti, i had tried to add mimeTypes - had tried with application/gzip or text/gzip it still wont work same like above screenshot, i plan to test with smaller gz file (uncompress) as for the current gz file if i uncompress the real size become 253MB (compress gz is 23MB) dont know if any differences or not. Please feel free to share your thoughts - thank you

Are you using Html framework or any other frameworks?

I tried with html framework and I was successfully loaded .gz and .json files. See this image.

But .gz file size is very small.

I will try with larger size.

Sorry @AsleshaKantamsetti for late reply, i attached the content of files in directory structure the only files is html and mostly use ajax and jquery inside the html though

Are you getting any error?

If possible, share your GitHub repository?

I created simple index.html to serve the .gz and json files and deployed to Azure Static web App.
The issue is with the Content-Encoding: gzip header in your AJAX request.
Remove the Content-Encoding: gzip header from your AJAX request because Azure automatically serves .gz files as compressed content and handling the compression.
Below is my complete index.html file.
index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Load Compressed GeoJSON</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pako/2.1.0/pako.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Load Compressed GeoJSON Data</h1>
  <button id="loadData">Load Data</button>
  <div id="output" style="margin-top: 20px;"></div>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("loadData").addEventListener("click", function () {
      const output = document.getElementById("output");
      output.innerText = "Loading data...";
      $.ajax({
        url: '/new_data.gz', 
        method: 'GET',
        xhrFields: {
          responseType: 'arraybuffer' 
        },
        success: function (compressedData) {
          try {
            let geojson;
            const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(compressedData);
            console.log("Uint8Array representation:", uint8Array);
            try {
              const decompressedData = pako.ungzip(uint8Array, { to: 'string' });
              console.log("Decompressed data:", decompressedData);
              geojson = JSON.parse(decompressedData);
            } catch (decompressionError) {
              console.log("Decompression failed, assuming plain JSON.");
              const textData = new TextDecoder().decode(compressedData);
              geojson = JSON.parse(textData);
            }
            console.log("GeoJSON parsed successfully:", geojson);
            output.innerText = "Data loaded successfully.";
            renderGeoJSONData(geojson);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error processing GeoJSON data:", error);
            output.innerText = "Error processing GeoJSON data. See console for details.";
          }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
          console.error("Failed to fetch compressed data:", error);
          output.innerText = `Failed to fetch data: ${status}`;
        }
      });
    });
    function renderGeoJSONData(data) {
      const output = document.getElementById("output");
      output.innerHTML = `<pre>${JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>`; 
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>

I created Azure Static web app with Standard Hosting Plan and Build Presets is Custom.


I am able to load files larger than 20 MB.
Azure Static Web App Output:

